# Can I save intellij "Find Tab" results with exclude/include state?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

When I go over search results (lets say references to some researched class function reference). I many times right click a reference and then "Exclude" to strike over and know I covered that one already.

Problem is, when I exit intellij or for some reason the "Find Usages" window is closed or overwritten, the state disappears then I don't know what I already covered.

Is there a smarter way to cover proper and track usages (based on my custom conditions) of over 1000 references?

Answer (score 1):

If you accidentaly close the tab, you can access the search results again by going to:

```
Edit -> Find -> Recent Find Usages
```

Unfortunatelly it is not preserved when you exit idea.

---

Alternatively you can click the following icon in the search results tab to export the results as a text file for future reference. There is no way to import it back into search results tab unfortunatelly.

[image]

---

Apart from these partial solutions, there are no other possibilities as far as I know. You may consider filing a feature request using JetBrains issue tracking system for IDEA:

> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes all of that I know, "export to text" is a mess to track and the "no way to import back" is killing it as an proper option for me, regarding "recent find usages"  I am also familiar with that one. However, that doesn't save the state (excluded/removed etc) also Intellij crashes is a terrible problem.

Comment: I know, but I'm afraid unfortunately there is nothing else. Updated my answer.

Comment: Opened an issue there thanks, maybe I am not using the right strategy for verifying proper method calls across the entire code, hope someone have a smarter way to do it and comment here.